# Hibernate Exception:Could not instantiate C3P0 connection pool

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

now i meet a prolem about c3p0 when using hibernate to query.

the exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [c3p0 bug] Only brand new IdentityTokenized's, with their identities just set, should be registered!!!
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.register(C3P0Registry.java:103)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.<init>(DriverManagerDataSource.java:74)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.unpooledDataSource(DataSources.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:96)
    ... 22 more
```

i cant find any useful info from google,does any buddy know the reason? Thanks!

BTW: my env is c3p0 0.9.0 and hibernate 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is C3P0 bug. I'd recommend to upgrade C3P0 to the latest version (currently 0.9.1.2, http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/).